# Joining 2 tables in MySql example code provided. Looking for assistance

Tags: mysql

The meaning of this question is to gather some answers for a task i am doing. I am trying to display the amount of products a vendor is supplying along with the vendor code next to it. I keep getting errored when trying to run the code listed below in Mysql workbench.

> Write a SQL statement to list V_CODE and V_NAME along with the number
> of products they supply (column name as ‘NUM_PRODS’) and the average
> price of product they supply (column name as ‘AVG_PROD_PRICE’).

Below is what i have currently but cant seem to get the V_CODE to ever display.

```sql
    SELECT VENDOR.VENDOR_CODE, VENDOR.V_NAME, count(distinct PRODUCT.P_CODE) as NUM_PRODS
    FROM VENDOR
    JOIN PRODUCT on VENDOR.V_CODE = PRODUCT.V_CODE
    GROUP BY VENDOR.V_NAME;
```

Just looking for some insight into how come I cannot display the VENDOR.V_CODE throught the SELECT statement.

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: You aren't selecting `V_CODE`... unless `VENDOR_CODE` is the same thing but from the `on` clause looks like they'd be different

Comment: *"how come I cannot display the VENDOR.V_CODE"* - Why can't you?  What's the specific problem you are observing?

Comment: VENDOR_CODE or V_CODE not in the GROUP BY Clause

Answer (score 1):

VENDOR_CODE is not shown because you are grouping by VENDOR.V_NAME. This means that there can be more than one value ​​in VENDOR_CODE. This is not possible in SQL. For example, you could use MAX(VENDOR.VENDOR_CODE) to get the highest VENDOR_CODE.

Answer (score 0):

VENDOR_CODE is not shown because you are grouping by VENDOR.V_NAME. This means that there can be more than one value ​​in VENDOR_CODE. This is not possible in SQL.
For example, you could use MAX(VENDOR.VENDOR_CODE) to get the highest VENDOR_CODE.

A list of possible functions with examples can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql_certificate/using_the_group_functions.htm#:%7E:text=Group%20by%20function%20establishes%20data,the%20rows%20in%20each%20group.)

Comment: I just grouped via Vendor_code and V_name. This seemed to work. Could you help me understand why this is working?

Comment: If you group with both, the VENDOR_CODE value can no longer take different values in one column, since a new column is created in your task for each different value.

Comment: Lets say for my own learning purposes. I am wanting to show all vendors and exactly how many products each vender offers. How would i then display the Vendors name + Products sold total and also the code of the vendor?